# Change the forecolor of textbox according to the string of that textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, uicolor

Is it possible to create an application that can change the fore-color of the textbox (and thereby changing the color of the text inside that textbox) depending on the text inside that textbox upon clicked of the button?

So far I can do it via `if-else`, and I feel that this is not the most efficient way to do all kinds of color.

[image]

I have this code

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "red" Then
        TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red
    ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "green" Then
        TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Green
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

**Question:** Can I do this without using if else? I mean can the system detects the string and rely on that string to change its fore-color or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, You need not do an additional event like button click, you can handle this in text_change event itself.`it will not throws any exception if the text is not a valid colour,just maintain the predefined color`.  you can do like this:

```
  Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.FromName(TextBox1.Text)
  End Sub
```

> According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromname(v=vs.110).aspx), A predefined color is also called a known color and
>   is represented by an element of the KnownColor enumeration. If the
>   name parameter is not the valid name of a predefined color, the
>   FromName method creates a Color structure that has an ARGB value of 0
>   (that is, all ARGB components are 0).

Answer (score 0):

```
TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.fromname(textbox1.text)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.